# I'm implementing the barcode all the things are working but after some time my App crashes

Tags: iphone, swift2

**
I'm  implementing the barcode all the things are working but aftersome time my App crashes when scanning the code continuously. or when i leave it for some time.**

=============================================

```
private func setupCaptureSession() {
    self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    do {
        let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
        //Add the input feed to the session and start it
        self.captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
        self.setupPreviewLayer({
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
            self.addMetaDataCaptureOutToSession()
        })
    } catch let setupError as NSError {
        self.showError(setupError.localizedDescription)
    }
}

private func setupPreviewLayer(completion:() -> ()){
    self.captureLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    if let capLayer = self.captureLayer {
        //capLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        capLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        cameraView.layer.masksToBounds=true;

        capLayer.frame = self.cameraView.frame
       // bounds CGRect = cameraView.layer.bounds;

        capLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.cameraView.frame.size.height);
        //capLayer.orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        capLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;


        self.view.layer.addSublayer(capLayer)
        completion()




    } else {
        self.showError1("An error occured beginning video capture.")
    }
} func addMetaDataCaptureOutToSession() {
    let metadata = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    self.captureSession.addOutput(metadata)
    metadata.metadataObjectTypes = metadata.availableMetadataObjectTypes
    metadata.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    for metaData in metadataObjects {
        let decodedData:AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = metaData as!AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        var theValueBarode = decodedData.stringValue
        //self.showError(theValueBarode)
        //self.click123()
        //self.addProduct(theValueBarode)
        if (theValueBarode == ""){

        }
        else{
            if (theValueBarode == "0083275099870" || theValueBarode == "9311960043718" || theValueBarode == "0051500241356" || theValueBarode == "54534232564" || theValueBarode == "0041167010563" )
            {
            self.showError(theValueBarode)
            theValueBarode = ""
            }
            else{

                self.showError1("This product is out of stock")
            }
        }
        func foundCode(code: String) {

                var code = code
                print(theValueBarode)
                self.showError(theValueBarode)
                self.addProduct(theValueBarode)

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message **and** the exact line of code that is causing the crash.

Comment: (Error: Could not cast value of type 'AVMetadataFaceObject' to 'AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject' )  ===> (for metaData in metadataObjects {
       
            var decodedData = metadataObjects[0] as!AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            var theValueBarode = decodedData.stringValue)